# Extract sub-matrices with connected values

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a matrix containing `NA` and `numeric` values ([Fig 1](http://[4]:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/s19mE.png)). The cells containing number are colored in blue. I want to extract sub-matrices where numeric cells connect to each other, i.e. the cells have values in adjacent cells.

Desired sub-matrices are illustrated by colorful borders in the [Fig 1](http://[4]:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/s19mE.png)).

Output will include 9 sub-matrices, with two examples shown in [Fig 2](http://[2]:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2k4O.png). Is it possible to do so? Thank you.

Matrix on Fig 1

```
time <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51)
    id1 <- c (NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id2 <- c(NA,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-23.08,NA,NA,NA,NA,-23.08,-23.08,-20.63,-18.03,NA,-16.67,-16.67,-18.03,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id3 <- c(-24.62,NA,NA,NA,NA,-35.71,-28.57,NA,NA,NA,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,NA,NA,NA,NA,-18.33,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-21.67,-23.33)
    id4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,-4,-32.86,NA,NA,-26.23,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-6,-6,-2,-23.33,-23.33,NA,NA)
    id5 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-23.81,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id6 <- c(NA,NA,NA,-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-10,-10,NA,-4,NA,NA,-10,NA,-10,-10,NA,-10,-10,-10,-10)
    id7 <- c(-10,-10,-10,NA,NA,-6.25,NA,NA,NA,NA,-10,NA,NA,-10,NA,-10,NA,NA,-10,NA,NA,-14,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id8 <- c (NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-10,-10,-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-6.25,NA,-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id9 <- c (NA,NA,-6.67,NA,-18,-6.67,NA,NA,NA,-12,-2.22,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id10 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    id11 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-2.22,-4.44,-8.51,-12.24,-8.51,-4.26,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
     df <- data.frame(time, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7, id8, id9, id10, id11)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: your submatrices might overlap on a non missing value not connected to one, or both, of the 2 intersecting matrices, what to do in such case ?

Comment: I ignored these edge cases and proposed a solution, but it's not exactly like your expected output, for example your two rectangles from bottom left go togeher as they are connected. Is this a mistake on your part that they were disconnected or is there a reason that I'm missing ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper you are right and do understand the logic. Some submatrices were defined incorrectly. Sorry for that. I will update the figure in case someone else has same question.

Comment: Thanks for updating, we can see now that the edge case presents itself in H21. It would be possible to update the code so the value is set to NA in the green subtable, if relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is converted to `raster` and then `clump`* is used to group clusters of connected cells.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(as.matrix(df[ , -1]))
rc <- clump(r)
```

The rest is basically "just" fiddling with indices to extract the correct values by group:

```
ix <- which(!is.na(df[ , -1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
d2 <- data.frame(ix[order(ix[ , "row"]), ],
                 g = rc@data@values[!is.na(rc@data@values)])

by(d2, d2$g, function(x){
  df[min(x$row):max(x$row) , c(1, min(x$col):max(x$col) + 1)]
})

# d2$g: 1   
#   time    id2    id3
# 1    1     NA -24.62
# 2    3 -23.08     NA
# 3    5 -23.08     NA
# 4    7 -23.08     NA
# ---------------------- 
#   d2$g: 2
#   time id6 id7
# 1    1  NA -10
# 2    3  NA -10
# 3    5  NA -10
# 4    7 -10  NA
# ----------------------
# [snip]
# d2$g: 9
#    time id6 id7
# 18   35 -10  NA
# 19   37  NA -10
# 20   39 -10  NA
# 21   41 -10  NA
# 22   43  NA -14
# 23   45 -10  NA
# 24   47 -10  NA
# 25   49 -10  NA
# 26   51 -10  NA
```

---

*Note that the `clump` function requires that the `igraph` package is available.

---

A visualization of the clumping:

```
plot(rc)
```

[image]

Comment: This way need shorter time to run on a matrix of 4000 rows x 150 cols. Great thanks to you @Henrik.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way, that's not short :).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

# get all non missing cells and their coordinates 
non_missing <- df %>%
  select(-time) %>%
  setNames(seq_along(.)) %>%
  rowid_to_column("Y") %>%
  gather(X,val,-Y,convert = TRUE) %>%
  na.omit %>%
  select(-val)

# get the pairs of connected cells
pairs <-non_missing %>%
  merge(.,.,by=NULL) %>%
  filter(pmax(abs(.[[1]]-.[[3]]),abs(.[[2]]-.[[4]])) <=1) %>%
  unite(a,1,2) %>%
  unite(b,2,3) 

# use network analysis get clusters
cluster_membership <- 
  graph_from_data_frame(pairs) %>% 
  clusters %>% 
  pluck(membership)

# use these clusters to extract sub tables
cluster_dfs <-
  cluster_membership %>%
  tibble(xy = names(.), id = .) %>%
  separate(xy,c('x','y'),convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(min_x = min(x), max_x = max(x),
            min_y = min(y), max_y = max(y)) %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  pmap(~df[-1][..1:..2, ..3:..4])
```

output :

```
# [[1]]
#      id2    id3
# 1     NA -24.62
# 2 -23.08     NA
# 3 -23.08     NA
# 4 -23.08     NA
# 
# [[2]]
#       id2    id3    id4
# 10 -23.08     NA     NA
# 11     NA -23.08     NA
# 12     NA -23.08     NA
# 13     NA -23.08     NA
# 14     NA -23.08     NA
# 15 -23.08     NA     NA
# 16 -23.08     NA     NA
# 17 -20.63     NA     NA
# 18 -18.03     NA     NA
# 19     NA -18.33     NA
# 20 -16.67     NA  -6.00
# 21 -16.67     NA  -6.00
# 22 -18.03     NA  -2.00
# 23     NA     NA -23.33
# 24     NA     NA -23.33
# 25     NA -21.67     NA
# 26     NA -23.33     NA
# 
# [[3]]
#      id3    id4    id5
# 4     NA  -4.00     NA
# 5     NA -32.86     NA
# 6 -35.71     NA     NA
# 7 -28.57     NA     NA
# 8     NA -26.23     NA
# 9     NA     NA -23.81
# 
# [[4]]
#   id6 id7
# 1  NA -10
# 2  NA -10
# 3  NA -10
# 4 -10  NA
# 
# [[5]]
#    id6 id7    id8
# 11  NA -10     NA
# 12 -10  NA     NA
# 13 -10  NA     NA
# 14  NA -10     NA
# 15  -4  NA  -6.25
# 16  NA -10     NA
# 17  NA  NA -10.00
# 
# [[6]]
#    id6 id7
# 18 -10  NA
# 19  NA -10
# 20 -10  NA
# 21 -10  NA
# 22  NA -14
# 23 -10  NA
# 24 -10  NA
# 25 -10  NA
# 26 -10  NA
# 
# [[7]]
#       id7 id8    id9
# 5      NA  NA -18.00
# 6   -6.25  NA  -6.67
# 7      NA -10     NA
# 8      NA -10     NA
# 9      NA -10     NA
# 10     NA  NA -12.00
# 11 -10.00  NA  -2.22
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] -6.67
# 
# [[9]]
# [1]  -2.22  -4.44  -8.51 -12.24  -8.51  -4.26
#
```

Comment: very nice.  I think there *might* be a clever way to turn a binary (0/1) matrix into an adjacency matrix by doing the right matrix operation (a quadratic form with a sparse matrix in the middle representing neighbourhood matrices).

Comment: Thousand thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper. You saved my day!

Comment: @BenBolker I'd love to see that too.